# Composer require PHP iconv OR mbstring extension

Tags: php, composer

I've installed the composer via "sudo apt install composer" which was installed successfully but when I try to run any composer command Example: "composer -v" its output this result on the terminal.

```
"The iconv OR mbstring extension is required and both are missing.
Install either of them or recompile php without --disable-iconv.
Aborting."
```

I'm using php 8.1

Comment: You will need to install the various PHP packages required by your tools. If you need support for multi-bite strings (always a good idea), then `sudo apt install php-mbstring`. Be sure to restart Apache afterwards.

Comment: I've already tried by run this command and restart apache but can't see mbstring in the list of module after run "php -m"

Answer (score 0):

You have to install missing extension: `mbstring` for Your PHP version:

```
apt install php8.1-mbstring
```